# On the orthogonal complement of a subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I was reading proofs of the Riesz Theorem, and in most version there is such a line.
Let $\phi$ be an element of the dual of a Hilbert space, where the base field is denoted $F$.
Then if $\ker \phi$ is the kernel of $\phi$, we can choose an element $z$ that is perpendicular to $\ker \phi$, and $z\neq 0$.

So here I have assumed that $\phi$ is not 0 everywhere in the space so there is at least a one-dimensional subspace in the complement of the kernel. How am I sure however that there is an element in the complement that is perpendicular to the kernel, except the zero vector?

I also  know that this is to show that the orthogonal complement of the kernel, which is a subspace, is not the set {0}.

I know you can decompose the Hilbert space by showing it is isomorphic to the direct sum of $F$ and $\ker\phi$. But can we not rely on this fact and still prove this statement?

Comment: If $\mathcal{N}(\phi)^{\perp} = \{0\}$, then $\mathcal{N}(\phi)=X$ is the whole space because $\mathcal{N}(\phi)^{\perp\perp}=\mathcal{N}(\phi)$ because $\mathcal{N}(\phi)$ is closed. Then $\mathcal{N}(\phi)=X$ gives $\phi=0$, which is represented by $\phi(\cdot)=\langle \cdot,0\rangle$.

Comment: When you say "closed" do you mean "the complement is open", ie topologically closed, or do you mean "if $x$ and $y$ is in the set then $ax+y$ is in the set", ie in the abstract-algebraic sense?

Comment: The null space is the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under the continuous linear functional $\phi$, which makes it closed in the topological sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $\phi$ is a continuous functional and so $\ker \phi = W$ is a closed subspace of $H$. Given a closed subspace $W$ of a Hilbert space $H$, you always have the direct sum decomposition $W \oplus W^{\perp} = H$. Thus, if $W \neq H$, you must have a non-zero vector in $W^{\perp}$.

Comment: How do you prove that the Hilbert space can be decomposed like that?

Comment: You have to work to show it. This usually involves showing that there is a notion of an orthogonal projection for which you need to be able to argue why, given a vector $v \in H$, you can find a unique vector $w \in W$ such that $||v - w||$ is minimized. Then $w$ will be (possibly even defined as) the orthogonal projection of $v$ on $W$ and you can write $v = w + (v - w)$ with $w \in W$ and $v - w \in W^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ denote the underlying Hilbert space and let $U:=\ker \phi$. Then we have

$$H=U \oplus U^{\perp}$$.

Now suppose that $U^{\perp}=\{0\}$. Then we have $H=U=\ker \phi$, thus

$$\phi(x)=0$$ for all$x \in H$

Comment: How do you prove the direct sum statement?